# Can I re-do what I have undone?

Tags: front-end

In *Mathematica* I can use the shortcut  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to undo some change I made to my notebook. But what if I undo too much and I have deleted something that was actually correct?

How can I *re-do what I have undone* (how can I restore it)?

Comment: Are you saying the `edit->redo` does not work after sometimes? I just tried it on few edits, and it works.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+Z?

Comment: @m_goldberg I didn't know about that shortcut.

Comment: I am going to close this post since the answer can be found in the documentation.